# hlsdemux pipeline

Tags: gstreamer

i have created a web server and hosted a AAC stream for HLS streaming, i am able to play the file on another machine using

```
gst-launch-0.10 souphttpsrc location=http://xx.xx.xx.xx/prog_index.m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! decodebin2 ! alsasink
```

but when i do this

```
souphttpsrc location=http://xx.xx.xx.xx/prog_index.m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! aacparse ! faad ! alsasink
```

i get this error in hlsdemux log and no audio output as aacparse doesn't receive any data

```
0:00:00.066165787  8139 0xb07098f0 INFO                hlsdemux gsthlsdemux.c:734:gst_hls_demux_loop:<hlsdemux0> First fragments cached successfully
0:00:00.066190861  8139 0xb07098f0 DEBUG               hlsdemux gsthlsdemux.c:680:switch_pads: Switching pads (oldpad:(nil))
0:00:00.066450610  8139 0xb07098f0 DEBUG               hlsdemux gsthlsdemux.c:757:gst_hls_demux_loop:<hlsdemux0> Sending new-segment. segment start:0:00:00.000000000
0:00:00.066510536  8139 0xb07098f0 DEBUG               hlsdemux gsthlsdemux.c:796:gst_hls_demux_loop:<hlsdemux0> error, stopping task
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
0:00:00.066541057  8139 0xb07098f0 DEBUG               hlsdemux gsthlsdemux.c:989:gst_hls_demux_stop_update:<hlsdemux0> Stopping updates thread
```

i am able to play the individual segment file using

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=fileSequence0.aac ! aacparse ! faad ! alsasink
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a caps: `... ! hlsdemux ! audio/mpeg ! aacparse ! ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding mpegtsdemux between hlsdemux and aacparse...
 because hlsdemux fetches uri till it get .ts streams n u will need mpegtsdemux to demux it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for the HLS audio stream:

```
... m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

or if you need to stream it again as an UDP:

```
... m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! decodebin ! audioconvert  ! faac ! audio/mpeg, stream-format=raw ! aacparse ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=230.0.0.1 port=5000
```